# what could be the problem with uv display

Tags: texturing, uv, shaders, uv-image-editor

I created textures in Substance painter, I don't understand why islands are displayed like this in Blender
some islands look darker in relation to other islands. this stands out a lot in the cycles and eevee render
[image]

[image]

Thank u, moonboots
[image]

Comment: Hello maybe it has to do with your normal map? Is its Image Texture node set to Non-Color instead of sRGB?

Comment: where can i track it?

Comment: when I press Shift+N the normals still look like a checkerboard. those islands that were lighter become darker....

Comment: hello, could you please pack your images and share your object?

Comment: unfortunately no(
this is a contract project, I can not distribute

Comment: You can just share a piece of your object